# Error during synchronous write using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, base64, synchronous

I have written code that parses a dictionary returned from Firebase containing images encoded using base64. I want it to simply write these images to file, and it does, but I receive the following error after my writes finish:

```
smalloc.cc:280: void node::smalloc::SliceOnto(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&): Assertion `end <= source_len' failed.
```

This is my code:

```
    // Iterate through each key in each page if each request
for (var key in request) {

    var obj = request[key];

    if (typeof (obj) == "object") {

        for (var prop in obj) {

            item++;
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {

                switch (prop) {

                    case "img":

                        var media = new ReceivedMedia(obj[prop]);

                        var filename = transaction.tid + "-" + item + "." + media.extension;
                        filename = filename.slice(10);
                        require('fs').writeFileSync(filename, media.b64, 'base64', function(err) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                        });
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My images come out fine, but the error is a little weird and I would prefer to not to occur. Would anyone have an idea as to why this is happening? That would be super helpful :)

Note: `ReceivedMedia` is a class I defined as:

```
function ReceivedMedia(media) {
    this.b64 = media.b64;
    this.extension = media.extension;
    this.posx = media.posx;
    this.posy = media.posy;
}
```

Side question: If I use `writeFile` instead of `writeFileSync` one of my images is corrupted and the other contains no data. If after that happens I run my node script again, the files save correctly. I would also like some explanation as to why that happens, from my understanding one of these is synchronous (`writeFileSync` I am guessing) and the other is asynchronous (`writeFile` I am assuming).

Comment: Here's where the error comes from in the native code for the V8 engine: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/src/smalloc.cc#L280.  It's an out of bounds argument on some sort of internal array manipulation.

Comment: I take it that there is no way for me to fix this or would I need to edit smalloc.cc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google search for your error message description found [this discussion of the issue in io.js](https://github.com/iojs/io.js/issues/661) and [this discussion in node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/9180) and it sounds like it is a bug that has been fixed (not sure if the fix has been released in a full build yet).

The node.js fix is [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/a35ba2f67dfcdf21b87f4326c6d67150f40224b6).

If you were desparate to fix it now in your own build, you'd have to apply the fix to your own code tree and rebuild it.  Otherwise, you'll have to investigate or inquire when this fix will get into an official release (I'm not personally sure how that process works for node.js).

Comment: I was looking at that fix and trying to see how I could implement it but I haven't had the time. I think i will keep exploring and if this turns out to fix the issue for me I will mark this as the answer :).

Comment: @Russell - This bug and fix is pretty clearly targeted at the exact same symptoms and the exact same ASSERT that is triggering for you.   While the proof would be in actually applying the fix and seeing the message go away, this bug and associated fix certainly looks like the smoking gun.  Per the [node.js changelog](https://nodejs.org/changelog.html), it does not appear that there has been a public release since this bug fix.  I can't tell from any node.js public resources if there is yet a planned release timing for v0.12.1.

Comment: I was able to get it. I cloned their git repo and installed it from source. I am now running 0.13.0-pre and the problem is gone.

I wasn't trying to argue that it wasn't but I wanted to make sure it solved the problem I was having and it did. Thank you for the assist :)